# Find all elements with matched set of values of specificed CSS property with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to find all elements in the web page which has the CSS property "font" with one of the values "700, 800, 900, bold, bolder". How can I do this with jQuery?

```
<a href="http://google.com" style="font:bold;">Google</a>
<p style="font:bolder;">Test</p>
<div style="font:700;">Test</div>
```

Comment: If you have access, you may want to consider giving these elements a custom class which you can easily access with `$('.myclass')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
var elements = $("*").filter(function () {
    var options = ["700", "800", "900", "bold", "bolder"];
    return $.inArray($(this).css('font-weight'), options) > -1;
});
```

Now you can manipulate your list of elements:

```
elements.css('background', '#f00'); // Highlights all elements with red bg.
```

See the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) for examples of how you can manipulate your DOM.

Comment: How can I do something, e.g append some text or add an attribute, to these elements?

Comment: Thanks so much. I have done a quick test over there :
http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/ZNM

. I expected the 2 "span" will be appended some new text, however they don't. Can you tell me what is the problem please?

Comment: That javascript is executing too early. Try wrapping it with `$(function () { ... });` as described in [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3), or move the `<script>` to the end of the `<body>`.

Comment: Never mind. I have figured it out. Here is what the documentation said : "Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 == false, but 0 !== false), if we're checking for the presence of value within array, we need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than) -1". Therefore at the end of the "return" I have to add the condition " > -1 ". Thank you for your help :D

Comment: Oh, I think you were using an old version of my answer. Try the current code in my answer which uses [`jQuery.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: Whoops -- You're right, `inArray` returns the index. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
$("*").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("font-weight") == "bolder" || 
           $(this).css("font-weight") == "bold" || ... ; 
});
```

Comment: How can I do something, e.g append some text or add an attribute, to these elements?